# Grails: Is there a way to have findAll() without a query but with pagination and sorting?

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm, findall

As I noticed in the answers of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758347/grails-no-signature-of-method-findall-is-applicable-for-argument-types-string) there are a few problems when testing finder methods in GORM.
I want to get all objects from `Something` and have support for sorting and pagination, so I wrote this:

```
SomethingListVO findAllSomethings(int offset = 0, int limit = 50) {
    def somethingCount = Something.count()
    def somethings = Something.findAll([max: limit,
                                            offset:offset,
                                            sort: "number",
                                            order: "asc"])
    return new SomethingListVO(somethingCount,somethings)
}
```

This can't work because if you want to add something like pagination or sorting you need to have a query. But if you add a query like `SELECT * FROM Something` your test will fail.

Is there any way to test this method (with pagination/sorting)?
[This approach](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/New-approach-to-mocking-domain-classes-in-Grails-unit-tests-td2529895.html) seems to provide more features but it won't work with my grails installation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just do this for your query

```
Something.list([max: limit,offset:offset,sort: "number",order: "asc"])
```